# Looping through lines of a text until a string // appears and write everything in separate lists

Tags: python, list, loops

I want to loop through the text and everytime a `G[i]` or `H[i]` appears I want the code to write what's under it into its own separate list until the string `//` appears and then move on to the next one.

That is my code so far:

```
ladida=[]
with open('D:/G2.txt') as f:
    namen = ("G","H")
    listencounter=0
    for line in f:
        if any(s in line for s in namen):
            listex=line.rstrip()
            ladida.append(listex)
print(ladida)
name=[]  
Name=[]  
with open('D:/G2.txt') as f:
    for i in range(len(ladida)):
        Name.append(name)
        for line in f:
            if ladida[i] in line:
                for line in iter(lambda: f.readline().rstrip(),'//'):            
                    extracted_line = line
                    extracted_list = extracted_line.split(",")
                    X = extracted_list[0]
                    print(Name[i])
                    Name[i].append(X)
```

However it only writes the G3 Part three times into one list.

This is my textfile:

```
G3
0.0, 0.0, 0.0
53.50805, 19.475337, 0.0
102.458385, 37.291802, 0.0
149.937529, 54.572797, 0.0
196.472482, 71.510135, 0.0
242.662047, 88.321762, 0.0
287.744278, 104.730352, 0.0
331.155303, 120.530673, 0.0
368.926371, 134.278218, 0.0
//
G4
1.0, 1.0, 1.0
53.50805, 19.475337, 0.0
102.458385, 37.291802, 0.0
149.937529, 54.572797, 0.0
196.472482, 71.510135, 0.0
242.662047, 88.321762, 0.0
287.744278, 104.730352, 0.0
331.155303, 120.530673, 0.0
368.926371, 134.278218, 0.0
//
H1
2.0, 2.0, 2.0
53.50805, 19.475337, 0.0
102.458385, 37.291802, 0.0
149.937529, 54.572797, 0.0
196.472482, 71.510135, 0.0
242.662047, 88.321762, 0.0
287.744278, 104.730352, 0.0
331.155303, 120.530673, 0.0
368.926371, 134.278218, 0.0
//
```

Comment: Why did you stop writing code before it was doing what you want?

Comment: Maybe it wrote the same part three times because your file just contains the same part three times with different headers?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The given Textfile is just an example of the structure of the actual textfile and it does differ at the beginning after the header. In the first loop it does what it's supposed to do but it doesnt continue to the the next part (G4)

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways to do that. You could for example do something like that:

```
with open('D:/G2.txt','r') as f:
    ls=f.read().split('\n//\n')
    for e in range(len(ls)-1):
        if ls[e].startswith(('G','H')):
            ls[e]=ls[e][1+len(str(e))+1:].replace('\n',',').replace(' ','').split(',')
        else:
            del ls[e]
print(ls)
```

Output: Each block is a list in this list:

```
[['0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '53.50805', '19.475337', '0.0', '102.458385', '37.291802', '0.0', '149.937529', '54.572797', '0.0', '196.472482', '71.510135', '0.0', '242.662047', '88.321762', '0.0', '287.744278', '104.730352', '0.0', '331.155303', '120.530673', '0.0', '368.926371', '134.278218', '0.0'], ['1.0', '1.0', '1.0', '53.50805',...]]
```

Happy coding!

PS: For your next questions: Please provide an example of the exact output you'd like to have to avoid misunderstandings.

Comment: thank you so much. i just realised it is not a 100 % of what iam looking for and i actually asked the wrong question^^. I need to split it up even more. From the G3-Block all the numbers which come first in line like (0.0, 53.50805, 102.458385, 149.937529 and so on...134.278218) have to be in a list and the numbers which come second in line (0.0, 19.475337, 37.291802, 54.572797 and so on). That makes 3 Lists for Block G3 and of course that should happen for every Block.Ps: the Blocks are still called G and H. sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: So you want to have the columns of each block converted to lists, that's a different story then ;-) you can read the whole file into a string and then use string index funtions like find() to get each block string. Then you could parse the block string or you can for example write each block to an own csv file and import each column to a list, e.g. with pandas tolist() function.